# @HtmlImport URL correct form

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am attempting to refactor some dart-polymer components to use the @HtmlImport annotation.

**.dart**

```
part of epimss_shared.components;

@CustomTag('associated-symptoms-form')
class AssociatedSymptomsForm extends PolymerElement {
  AssociatedSymptomsForm.created() : super.created();

  @override
  void attached() {
    super.attached();
  }
}
```

**.html**

```
<polymer-element name='associated-symptoms-form'>
  <template>
    <div layout horizontal center> 
      <h1>Symptoms</h1>
  </template>

   <script type = 'application/dart' src='associated_symptoms_form.dart'></script>
</polymer-element>
```

**library**

The library epimss_shared.components; is part of the imported epimss.shared library.

```
@HtmlImport('../components/tooltip/tool_tip.html')
@HtmlImport('../components/misc/associated_symptoms_form.html')
library epimss_shared.components;

import 'dart:html' as dom;

import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:epimss_shared/epimss_shared.dart';
import 'package:epimss_shared/epimss_shared_client.dart';

part '../components/tooltip/tool_tip.dart';
part '../components/misc/associated_symptoms_form.dart';
```

When I attempt to use the component, the application is not displayed with the following console error:

```
'package:epimss_shared/components/misc/associated_symptoms_form.dart': error: line 1 pos 6: url expected
part of epimss_shared.components;
     ^: package:epimss_shared/components/misc/associated_symptoms_form.dart
```

#### The peculiar thing is this - if I creat a new component with a different name with everything remaining the same (as done with the tooltip component shown in the library) there is no problem at all!

It seems that previous information of the component is cached and is being reused.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have been scouring the docs and stackoverflow but cannot find any info on how to terminate pub serve. Stopping and starting my eclipse does not seem to work. Removing the .pub alone does not work either. The command |pub serve| does not seem to help. How do I kill pub serve?

Comment: When you close Eclipse it should be stopped as well automatically. I forgot you use the Eclipse plugin. In DartEditor is a `pub serve` view which has a small square red button to stop `pub serve`. `pub serve` and the `.pub` directory are the only places I can imagine where such things could be cached. If this doesn't help, I have no idea.

Comment: Can it have to do with you using part files? Did you use a part file for the new (working) component as well?

Comment: In eclipse console view there is a similar red square with the 'terminate' tooltip. Clicking this terminates the running server. This does not work. Closing eclipse, removing all .pub folders, restarting eclipse and and running the app does not work either. Yes, part files were used for both examples.

Comment: Where is the cache for pub serve?

Comment: `pub cache` serves in memory, this is why I suggested killing it to make it forget everything. `.pub` seems to contain some precompiled things, don't know details.

Comment: Thanks. I will try some things to see if anything helps.

Comment: I loaded on the current DEV of DartEditor, deleted all .pub and kill pub serve, but the result is the same. The cache MUST be somewhere.

Comment: Maybe it's not a cache issue at all.

Comment: Possibly. I am thinking of filing a bug.